# Why does the tab key not work while writing questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, asking-questions

While I write a question/answer on Stack Overflow, and I want paste code, 
it does not always paste correctly formatted.

For example:

```
void helloworldSpammer(int times) 
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
        }
```

Then what I would want to do is use the tab key to remove the extra tabs from lines 2 - 7 (shift - tab) (because they don't like it when I would just add a tab on line 1).

When I do so, it is not removing the tabs, but the cursor jumps back to the title textbox. The same occurs with tabbing forward: the cursor jumps to the tags textbox.

Instead, I would have to backspace this all, instead of using tab to remove the extraneous indentation.

On a little piece of code, it is not that big of a deal, but when you paste 20 lines, it is annoying.

**Is this a bug?
Can this be fixed, or is there a reason that the tab key does not indent?**

Comment: Maybe it's a not-so-subtle suggestion to use spaces for indentation instead of tabs :)

Comment: @AndrewMedico and why would they want you to use spaces? please explain me, that's what i'm asking ;)

Comment: Tabs are superior, but fortunately it's trivial to convert from tabs before pasting to fit in with an unsympathetic world.

Comment: Editors that translate TAB to spaces are my best friends in the world. :)

Comment: [Use spaces!](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/657/47845)

Comment: @JoJo Because tabs can change width when displayed with different configurations, so what you see as well formatted can be competely wrong on a different editor. If you use spaces you are sure that everywhere the spacing is displayed as you want. This is particularly true in situations where you want to copy-paste code to (e.g.) SO, where using tabs will only mess up the final formatting. If you use spaces from the start you don't have copy-pasting problems.

Comment: I strongly agree that the TAB key should NOT work in the editor (as it would contadict normal browser behaviour), but it'd be great if there was some indent/outdent hotkey combo like CTRL+[ and CTRL+] or similar... does one exist?

Comment: This is an extreme annoyance and there should be a checkbox to toggle that option on and off. How hard could it be?

Comment: Some files require TABs. Make and Whitespace for example. For those code it is absolutely no option to convert TABs into spaces.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

General internet browser convention dictates that the <kbd>tab</kbd> key be used to cycle between various controls on the page, and not to represent the `\t` character, even when a text input control has focus.

For the site to fight this would be both somewhat difficult, because the browser is designed to *not* do what you are asking of it, and also violates the user expectation of this virtually ubiquitous web browser feature.  While this may be *possible*, it's generally not a very good idea.

Personally I'd suggest using something other than a web browser for generating/formatting code, at least when you have more than just a bit of it.  Whether that's a full IDE, or simply a basic text editor, you're probably better off using something besides a web browser's textbox for a non-trivial amount of code.

Comment: ok, i understand now, but why is the 1st line formatted wrong when i post it. in my editor, it's always formatted right, but when i paste code here, the first line is formatted bad (like in example)

Comment: It's because you're not copying your code correctly.  You're not copying the whitespace before the first line of code.  You're copying code like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r0gUf.png) instead of like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FgEas.png)

Comment: @JoJo the first line is actually the only one that's indented correctly. Unnecessary indentation makes users have to scroll <-> on more complex examples, which is _almost_ as annoying as reading poor formatting - especially relevant on mobile/small screens.

Comment: @AD7six yes, i know but the code in the example doesn't look really good formatted. if it stays like that, there will always be someone that edits it, so why don't do it yourself? btw Servy thanks for your hint

Comment: @JoJo Because that's rude and inconsiderate of other's time.

Comment: @JoJo having indent buttons in the js editor would help. I assume thats been asked for before though.

Comment: @AD7six yeah! that would be great! :). so, that is something they should do.

Comment: @JoJo there's a [long standing feature request for that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar).

Comment: I agree with you in general. But the worst are those code examples that are right in between a `one-liner` and something that is probably better done in an editor. Thats my commiserating for the day.

Comment: there are other issues with tab characters in the answer box; e.g. lines at left margin; try to correct; and the line goes **->POP!** back into place (but with an *extra* tab or space, now). (if you paste code with tabs and it looks like the OP's, just: <cursor to beginning of code> [↓] [shift]+[→] [ctrl]+[c] [←] [↑] [ctrl]+[v]  

still… I plan to see if I can figure out how to set up a notepad++ "stackoverflowcode" language, set tabs to be 4 spaces, plus a macro to switch and auto-format. then, just set to C++ in N++, type code (or paste from IDE); hit the macro to switch language/autoformat.

Comment: Screw this and give us tabs!

Comment: It is a very strange thing. I understand everything about how browser understands Tab press, but such a necessary and frequently used site (stackoverflow) and everytime you should do something straange, use IDE, text editors, etc for writing your questions. Why not just use some js editors?  Writing questions in browser is extremely uncomfortable.

Answer (score 15):

**Don't use tabs. Use spaces.** At least when posting answers on Stack Overflow.

The eternal war between tabs and spaces is a silly one, they each have their purposes. Spaces are required to precisely line up identifiers in code, and I'm <strike>slightly</strike> OCD so I appreciate that. Tabs have the advantage of being configurable, so that you can have your text editor interpret a tab as 8 spaces and I can set mine to 2 spaces, and we're both happy. I therefore use tabs in languages where I don't care about lining things up (e.g. HTML and CSS), and spaces in languages where I do (e.g. C++). But more to the point, I've found that tabs just *do not work well* with the markdown interpreter Stack Exchange uses. I cannot tell you how many times I've cursed when trying to edit a poorly-formatted post that used tabs for indentation, rather than spaces. In fact, it seems there's almost a pattern: when questions are horribly formatted, they are almost always pasted in from a text editor that was set to use tabs, instead of converting tabs to spaces.

Of course, that doesn't mean you can't use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. I do it all the time, I have just configured it to insert 4 spaces when I press it. Much easier, and less wear and tear on my spacebar.

A lot of people, including Servy, recommend composing code in an external text editor, and then copying and pasting it to the answer box. I say pish-posh, mainly because it's fun to say, but also because I usually don't want to take the time to fire up another application just to compose a simple answer. Unless it's something I have to test, which is unusual with simple sample code snippets, I'll type it right into the answer box. Like you, I get extremely frustrated with the default handling of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

There is a good reason for it. Again, like Servy points out, it is common convention in applications for the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to switch focus between the various controls that receive input. Developers—and this includes web designers—should never override this behavior, as it may interfere with accessibility, particularly by users who do not use a mouse to navigate around a user interface.

But you—as a user—can customize this behavior. On Chrome, I use a couple of extensions to make my life easier:

- [balpha's stackexchange-tab-editing extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts), which makes the <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> keys in the post editor behave more like they do in text editors.
- [chrome-textarea-formatter](https://code.google.com/p/chrome-textarea-formatter/), which makes *any* text box (of your choosing) on a web page behave more like one in a text editor. You activate this extension on-demand, by clicking an icon that appears in your browser's address bar. (Do make sure that you customize this one to insert 4 spaces upon presses of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, rather than inserting a literal tab.)

I'm sure that there are similar extensions for other browsers, but despite the Chrome team's best efforts, that's the only browser I use in Windows.

It is also worth pointing out that you can take advantage of the built-in "Code Format" feature of the markdown editor. Selecting a block of text and clicking the `{}` button (or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) will indent or unindent by 4 spaces. This is a *lot* faster than press either <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> for each line. Unfortunately, there is no "increase indent" or "decrease indent" feature—all you get is a toggle. But there is [a user script for that, too](https://stackapps.com/questions/2440/increase-decrease-indentation-buttons-for-the-editor).

Comment: does visual studio convert tabs into spaces? and also thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @JoJo It is a setting, configured per-language.

Comment: i checked, and for me it is. i never changed it. btw, i have no idea how to unindent by 4 spaces with 'ctrl + k' or {} button.

Comment: @jojo Select the text block, and press Ctrl+K. It is a toggle switch. If the block is indented with 4 spaces, those spaces will be removed. It only works on Stack Overflow, not in Visual Studio. There, it adds a comment (I think).

Comment: ok, i tried it and this is what i got: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eBCjj.png  -->  becomes : http://i.stack.imgur.com/yMmVP.png . what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @JoJo You have to highlight the *whole* block, all the way to the ends of the lines. You missed the space in front of the first brace, so it doesn't know how to modify the indentation of the block. In other words, [do this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XfZ5g.png).

Comment: "I usually don't want to take the time to fire up another application just to compose a simple answer."  You don't leave an IDE/editor/etc. running all the time? :)

Comment: @Josh Hah, no. For one thing, I do all of my development work in virtual machines, which are not always running. The only editor I have installed locally is Notepad. Also, I answer SO questions from whichever computer I'm sitting in front of, which is often a personal MacBook Pro running OS X. Since I primarily answer Windows programming questions, it's less helpful than you'd think. :-)

Comment: "pish-posh" really is fun to say.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Notepad++`; I always write/format Code snippets in `Notepad++` and then paste the code in the question. helps tremendously with the formatting ;)

Comment: I don't have trouble with formatting.  But if I paste it wrong, I really want to be able to quickly edit it in the texbox.

Answer (score 4):

There should be a feature one can opt-into which would get Tab to insert N spaces. Default N=4.

On Windows, this is easy to do already, without asking Stack Exchange to change their software: using AutoHotkey and filtering based on "Stack Overflow" appearing in the Window title bar.

Comment: Can you share your AutoHotkey script with us? Will it work with Ubuntu and macOS?

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox, I use [It's All Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) to edit in an external browser. Much more convenient than the textarea...

Answer (score 3):

I posted the same questino a long ago in the meta for stackoverflow and a moderator made a script for me to use on chrome that modified the behaviour of tab to insert 4 spaces.
When they changed the meta, it got lost.

EDIT - found the question

[Let the user choose what the TAB does in the editor with caveats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122529/let-the-user-choose-what-the-tab-does-in-the-editor-with-caveats)

found the answer

https://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts