# SO renderer breaks Makefile syntax

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting

The following answer contains an GNU Makefile:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27190627/402322

I tried to use the Makefile on my system, but it does not work, because the syntax is broken.

I edited the answer and corrected the syntax. Indented lines need to be indented with exactly one tabulator and no spaces.

But after saving the change I realized, that the answer gets rendered in a way, which breaks the syntax of the file. The SO rendering replaces the tabulator with 4 spaces.

Comment: _@ceving_ Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131213/can-you-make-valid-makefiles-without-tab-characters/21920142#21920142) please. The more recent versions of make don't require tabs strictly anymore.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Maybe. But it is no excuse for SO to break content. It is simply not okay to convert a tab into spaces. Think about [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)).

Comment: @ceving https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255953/why-does-the-tab-key-not-work-while-writing-questions-answers

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That question is about entering a TAB in the browser.

Comment: [Meta SE duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285838/308065).

Comment: Better title: SO Renderer Fights Back: Episode 3 -- Makefile Syntax

Comment: Fixed in GNU Make 3.82, released in July 2010.

Comment: As @Cœur says the syntax is not broken, you simply have to specify `RECIPEPREFIX` as 4 spaces

Comment: The problem is not that the changed (tab -> space replaced) makefile necessarily breaks. The problem is that on a website that is explicitly and exclusively about programming you can't enter ASCII code without worrying that the rendering engine will _change the syntax_. Just because modern systems also work with the changed version doesn't mean it's not broken.

Answer (score 19):

There's a workaround, as per [mbomb007's answer to the Meta Stack Exchange feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294870/308065). Writing this:

```
<pre><code>Hello!
This is a tab:&#9;:bat a si sihT</code></pre>
```

makes:

```
Hello!
This is a tab:	:bat a si sihT
```

This, however, is by no means perfect, since you have to manually escape `&`, `<` and `>`. It is simply a hack.

Comment: I don't understand why this has so many downvotes. It's a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: @JL2210 It's not a solution, though. It's a tricky, hackish workaround. The problem isn't solved by it.

Comment: Well, Stack Exchange has made it clear that they're not going to support this (see [meta-tag:status-declined] on the Meta.SE duplicate that you posted), so... I guess this is the best *tricky, hackish workaround* we have.

Comment: @JL2210 But it's a poor decision and woefully insufficient. I can come up with one reason every ten seconds for… some time, I think, that preserving tabs is a good idea.

Comment: The workaround is to stop blindly copy/pasting code from the internet. Use your fingers and brain instead!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if you're gonna start expecting all programmers to _understand_ the code they copy from the internet, global productivity is going to grind to a halt.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It takes both my fingers and my brain to copy and paste code from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

It is by design. In [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294874/274323) to the MSE question that was mentioned earlier Shog9 provides reasons why it has been done this way (tl;dr; to make code in the snippets looks well for everyone).

As the one who used to use makefiles a lot I can understand your pain. On the other hand, I remember time when I was working with an old markdown editor (on another site) that did not change tabs into spaces. It was a huge disaster to format code to make it looks fine for everyone and we dreamed for such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can use the special variable `.RECIPEPREFIX` to change the character used to indicate code from tabulator to something else that won't be scrambled by the renderer.

E.g.:

```makefile
.RECIPEPREFIX = >

prog: foo.cc bar.cc baz.cc
> g++ $^ -o $@
```