# Tabs are discouraged. Should we use them anyway in answers about make where they are meaningful?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

For better formatting tabs are discouraged in questions and answers. See, for example, the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example section of the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

> Also, use spaces instead of tabs – tabs might not get correctly formatted on Stack Overflow.

However tabs are meaningful in Makefiles where they cannot be replaced by spaces. When answering a make question and suggesting some make code, I always comply with the no-tabs recommendation and replace them by 4 spaces. It frequently happens that the OP copy-paste the suggested code and post a comment indicating that it doesn't work:

```
Makefile:NN: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

What shall I do? Ignore the no-tabs recommendation in make code snippets or always explain that, after copy-pasting, the leading spaces in recipes shall be replaced by tabs?

Comment: I found this similar question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386647/so-renderer-breaks-makefile-syntax . Not sure that answers there are up-to-date.

Comment: Tabs are replaced with blanks, both in preview and when actually posting; see the indent in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68760915/3266847), for example. When opening in the editor, you can see that it's a tab, but when rendered, it's not.

Comment: @Damien Thanks for the link, I missed that. It more or less makes my question a duplicate, I guess.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Wow, and I didn't try this myself! (well I tried something similar but only in the editor, which was stupid). Thanks a lot, this completely answers my question: using tabs or spaces cannot make any difference for the copy-paste.

Comment: I don't think it always was like that! I remember copying from questions and getting tabs.

Comment: I vaguely think this changed when Stack Overflow switched to Commonmark from their own in-house Markdown renderer.