# Different results for code snippet in preview and after posting

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I just encountered a strange situation. I want to post a code snippet but after submitting the result is different from what I have in the preview. I also tested this in the browser console which shows me the same result as the preview. So after submitting the output is wrong.

This is the code

```
const tabbedString = `Prefix    Name    Last Name   Email   Phone   Age Role
    Jim Loco    jilo@fox.com        32  Admin
Mrs.    Sara    Foo safoo@fox.com   124389  44  Admin
Mr. John    Deer    jodeer@fox.com      37  Developer`

const parsedString = tabbedString.split('\n').map((line) => line.split('\t'))

console.log(parsedString)
```

Expected output

```
[
  [
    "Prefix",
    "Name",
    "Last Name",
    "Email",
    "Phone",
    "Age",
    "Role"
  ],
  [
    "",
    "Jim",
    "Loco",
    "jilo@fox.com",
    "",
    "32",
    "Admin"
  ],
  [
    "Mrs.",
    "Sara",
    "Foo",
    "safoo@fox.com",
    "124389",
    "44",
    "Admin"
  ],
  [
    "Mr.",
    "John",
    "Deer",
    "jodeer@fox.com",
    "",
    "37",
    "Developer"
  ]
]
```

When I create this as snippet, as already mentioned, in the preview i get this expected result. However, after submitting its different.

```js
const tabbedString = `Prefix    Name    Last Name   Email   Phone   Age Role
    Jim Loco    jilo@fox.com        32  Admin
Mrs.    Sara    Foo safoo@fox.com   124389  44  Admin
Mr. John    Deer    jodeer@fox.com      37  Developer`

const parsedString = tabbedString.split('\n').map((line) => line.split('\t'))

console.log(parsedString)
```

Comment: I just thought its probably because SO replaces tabs with 4 spaces, when actually posting.

Comment: Yes, like you say, there is no tab char in there anymore. So it can't split there.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255953/4014959

Comment: @The Fool: The TABs are preserved in the source, but rendered as spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the escape sequence for the tab character in your string.

```js
const tabbedString = `Prefix\tName\tLast Name\tEmail\tPhone\tAge\tRole\n\t\tJim\tLoco\tjilo@fox.com\t\t32\tAdmin\nMrs.\tSara\tFoo\tsafoo@fox.com\t124389\t44\tAdmin\nMr.\tJohn\tDeer\tjodeer@fox.com\t\t37\tDeveloper`

const parsedString = tabbedString.split('\n').map((line) => line.split('\t'))

console.log(parsedString)
```